# Disable javascript generation from typescript if an error is detected

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript, compilation

I have started to use typescript in Visual Studio and it seems that the default behavior is to generate javascript even if the error is found. So really the only static compilation output I can see is the red underline if an error is detected. It is easy to overlook that really, so I would prefer if no js or some js that throws exception is generated in this case or some other form of explicit error. Is it possible to set up Visual Studio to do something like that?

Update:
It seems there is an option to not emit on error, but that leaves the old js code, which is not a desired outcome, so I would like to hear about other simple options if they exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the **noEmmitOnError** option to true in **tsconfig.json**.

eg.

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I can't get it to work properly with tsconfig.json, sometimes it stops generating .js at all, sometimes VS gives some weird exceptions. Is it fully supported by VS?

Comment: Seems tsconfig.json fully overrides default, so we need "compileOnSave": true. Another problem is that it does not generate the code now, but it leaves the old javascript which is even worse in my opinion. Can something be done with it?

Comment: the same option should be available in the visual studio project files somewhere. As for the old files, you could delete them when the compilation starts (if your build tool allows for that kind of actions on build)

Comment: I am just using pure Visual Studio now without any build tool and was wondering if it's possible to do in VS.

Comment: you should be able to do something using the compile hooks provided by VS. I would recommend you ask a different question for that though. You can read more about the hooks here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724.aspx

Comment: I'll wait a bit if someone has a suggestion here, but thanks for the idea anyway.